# Compare the existing neo4j with a csv and add missing nodes and relationships from a csv

Tags: csv, neo4j, py2neo

Below is my code to create a neo4j relationship by reading from a csv file.

```
import csv
from py2neo import neo4j, cypher, authenticate, Graph
from py2neo import node, rel
import py2neo
authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "bhatt1234")
graph_db = neo4j.Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
ifile = open('agent_send.csv',"rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
rownum = 0
for row in reader:
colnum = 0
for col in row:
rel =  graph_db.merge({))
rownum += 1
ifile.close()
```

SO ,

I am looking to build a process to do daily imports from a csv to an already exisiting neo 4j. For that I need to use merge() statement. But I am grappling with using merge in py2neo. I need to use the merge between my csv and already existing nodes and relations in my neo4j db.

```
    :START_ID(Agent),:END_ID(Agent),TXN_KEY,Amount,SendTime,PayTime,:TYPE
       AEX053163,AEX010922,5000000000107593411,20.0,1361439,1362963.0,Agent_Send
AKJ063072,AS1034942,5000000000108495674,220.0,1361434,1362369.0,Agent_Send
ADT326742,AMX002998,5000000000106488543,1000.0,1361435,1363053.0,Agent_Send
ARA031639,AED100363,5000000000106029876,1669.0,1361424,1362506.0,Agent_Send
AKC403616,ADJ122111,5000000000107872144,180.0,1361415,1362680.0,Agent_Send
```

Above is a CSV which has a relation. So, how do I put this relation under g.merge()?

Comment: Which version of neo4j/py2neo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , I was able to achieve the results by using LOAD CSV. It is a very handy utility to do everyday ETLs to the exisitng database.

Answer (score 0):

The `create()` function returns a tuple of all entities created which has the length of the number of arguments.

You are trying to unpack the tuple (which has length 5 in your case) into three variables: `Agent,Agent,rel`.

Try to store the result in a single variable:

```
result = graph_db.create(...)

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Hi , storing the result in a single variable is just creating nodes and not any relationships between them.

Comment: Then you do something wrong with the node/rel definition. Your error is not related to creating relationships.